# Eclipse unable to find action set of old plug-ins

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I was following the instructions from [PDE Does Plug-ins](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-PDE-does-plugins/PDE-intro.html) to create a few first plug-ins for Eclipse. Everything worked out this far. But when starting the second instance of Eclipse I get the following error information in my console.

General Information:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.7.0_21
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.sdk.ide -refresh
Command-line arguments:  -product org.eclipse.sdk.ide -data C:\Users\Stefan\workspace/../runtime-EclipseApplication -dev file:C:/Users/Stefan/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Eclipse Application/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consoleLog -clean -refresh
```

Error Messages:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-11-17 14:15:39.449
!MESSAGE Unable to find Action Set: HelloWorldPlugin.actionSet

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-11-17 14:15:39.455
!MESSAGE Unable to find Action Set: myplugin.actionSet

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-11-17 14:15:39.456
!MESSAGE Unable to find Action Set: PluginTest.actionSet
```

When closing the second instance of Eclipse:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 2 2013-11-17 14:16:10.359
!MESSAGE Invalid property category path: ValidationPropertiesPage (bundle: org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui, propertyPage: org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.propertyPage.project.validation)
```

As you can see I already tried the `-clean` and `-refresh` command line parameters and editing the `workbench.xmi/.xml`, both without success.

I assume these error messages are caused by plug-ins that have previously existed in my workspace, but are no longer existent. Unfortunately these are not listed under 'Installed Plugins' so I cannot remove them this way.

Comment: I am also trying to find out a solution for this kind of issue

Answer (score 1):

Worth checking out your run configurations for what Plugin's are being looked for:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach didn't solve the problem. When I deactivate one of my plugins here, I get additional messages of missing actionSets (for those deactivated plugins)... Seems like the actionSets are registered somewhere inside the IDE but are not coupled to the specific plugins.